# CakePHP login when trying to acces controller

Tags: session, cakephp, controller

im having troubles with a web app that a teacher ask me to modify, the problem its that i dont know about cakePHP and i have been having troubles.After reading a lot, i think i have grasped the basics of the framework. My problem now its that i have a link  in a view so i call a function in the controller to retrive data from the model, the problem its that each time i try to acces the function , the app makes me log in, and the idea its that it shouldnt.
I dont know exactly how the session handling on cakePhp works so, im requesting some help.
the code for the controller its this:

```
<?php
class RwController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Rw';
// var $paginate = array(
    // 'Tip' => array(
        // 'limit' => 1,
        // 'order' => array(
            // 'tip.created' => 'desc'
        // ),
    // ),
    // 'Evento' => array(
        // 'limit' => 1,
        // 'order' => array(
            // 'evento.fecha' => 'desc'
        // ),
    // )
// );
function map() {
    $this->helpers[]='GoogleMapV3';
}
function pageForPagination($model) {
    $page = 1;
    // $chars = preg_split('/model:/', $this->params['url']['url'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    // #print_r($chars);
    // if(sizeof($chars) > 1 && sizeof($chars) < 3) {
        // #echo "Belongs to ".$model.": \n";
        // #echo var_dump($chars);
    // }
    // $params = Dispatcher::parseParams(Dispatcher::uri());
    // echo "<p>".var_dump($params)."</p><br />";
    #echo $this->params['named']['model'].$model;
    #echo $this->params['named']['page'];
    $sameModel = isset($this->params['named']['model']) && $this->params['named']['model'] == $model;
    $pageInUrl = isset($this->params['named']['page']);
    if ($sameModel && $pageInUrl) {
        $page = $this->params['named']['page'];
    } else {
        #echo var_dump($this->passedArgs);
    }
    $this->passedArgs['page'] = $page;
    return $page;
}

function index() {
    $this->log('indexeando esta chingadera','debug');
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->loadModel('Evento');
    $this->loadModel('Tip');

    $dataEvento = $this->Evento->find('all');
    $dataTip = $this->Tip->find('all');

    $page = $this->pageForPagination('Evento');
    $this->paginate['Evento'] = array(
        'contain' => false,
        'order' => array('Evento.fecha' => 'desc'),
        'limit' => 1,
        'page' => $page
    );
    $dataEvento = $this->paginate('Evento');

    $page = $this->pageForPagination('Tip');
    $this->paginate['Tip'] = array(
        'contain' => false,
        'order' => array('Tip.created' => 'desc'),
        'limit' => 1,
        'page' => $page
    );
    $dataTip = $this->paginate('Tip');

    $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
    $this->set('eventos', $dataEvento);
    $this->set('tips', $dataTip);
    $this->set('rw');

    if(isset($this->params['named']['model'])) {
        if (strcmp($this->params['named']['model'], 'Evento') == 0) {
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $this->render('/elements/ajax_rw_evento_paginate');
                return;
            }
        } elseif (strcmp($this->params['named']['model'], 'Tip') == 0) {
            if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $this->render('/elements/ajax_rw_tip_paginate');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

function about($id = null) {
    $this->Rw->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('rw', $this->paginate());
}

function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        $this->Auth->allow(array('index', 'about'));
}

function getCentros($id){
    $this->loadModel('Centro');
    $this->log('getcentros','debug');
    if( sizeof($id) > 1){
        $this->set('centros', $this->Centro->query("SELECT centros.id, name, latitud ,longitud 
                                                        FROM `centros`,`centrosmateriales` 
                                                            WHERE centros.id = centro_id 
                                                                AND material_id ='".$id[0]."' 
                                                                    OR material_id='".$id[1]."'"));
    }elseif( sizeof($id) >0) {
        if($id == 0){
            $this->set('centros', $this->Centro->find('all'));
        }else{
            $this->set('centros', $this->Centro->query("SELECT centros.id, name, latitud ,longitud 
                                                            FROM `centros`,`centrosmateriales` 
                                                                WHERE centros.id = centro_id 
                                                                    AND material_id ='".$id[0]."'"));
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}


}   
?>
```

Edit:

The function im calling is getCentros().

this is what i have in app_controller.

```
<?php 
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth', 'RequestHandler');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Time', 'Session', 'Js', 'Paginator', 'GoogleMapV3');
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which function is forcing the login? Nothing here sticks out as to why it's logging out. A few things to check or you can paste the code in your question is: appController.php could have a setting in the beforeFilter() forcing login on each page refresh of a view : Or check the contents of App/config/core.php, that is generally where the session params are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('*'));
```

it allows you to access all functions inside the controller.

But before that make sure that you have access on the controller with out errors because your controller name is like this

```
class RwController extends AppController {

}
```

may be it want like this

```
class RwsController extends AppController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which function you are trying to call but if cake tries to log you in and you don'want this add the function to:

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('index', 'about'));
```

in your beforefilter

Comment: theres i a beforefilter function inside the RwController and there's already a line like this, its that what you mean?
i didn't add this line so im not sure what it does;

Comment: The line allows you to view the "index" and "about" page without the need to login. You can also use a "*" (see answer below) to allow access to all functions without login in.